# How to extract inner array out of nested array?

Tags: arrays, perl, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have the following code which defines a nested array and then loops through the array and outputs it.  I would like to use the commented out line to extract the inner arrays but it doesn't work because it flattens out the inner arrays. I instead have to use the subsequent three lines.  How can I get the commented out line to work properly?

```
use Data::Dumper;    
my @arr1;
for $i (0..9)
{
    my @arr2;
    my @arr3;
    for $j ('A'..'D') {
        push @arr2, $j;
        push @arr3, int(rand(100));
    }
    push @arr1, [$i, \@arr2, \@arr3]; 
}
for $linkarray (@arr1) {
    #my ($i, @arr2, @arr3) = @$linkarray;   
    my $i = @$linkarray[0];
    my @arr2 = @$linkarray[1];
    my @arr3 = @$linkarray[2];
    print "i: $i\narr2: " . Dumper(@arr2) . "\narr3: " . Dumper(@arr3) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: You pushed in array references, so you should collect array references when you unpack, not arrays.  `my ($i, $arr2_ref, $arr3_ref) = @$linkarray;`

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html

Comment: How do I then deference those references to use them like a normal array?

Comment: `my @arr2 = @$arr2_ref;`  or you can just use them directly: `my $first = $arr2_ref->[0];`

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html

Comment: Is it necessary to use `->` ?

Comment: Yes.  Read up on references.

Comment: No. `$ref->[0]` and `${$ref}[0]` are equivalent. That said, `$ref->[0]` is much more readable.

Comment: Tip: If you want to dump an array or hash, pass a reference to it to Dumper. You'll get less confusing results.

Answer (score 1):

If you're having trouble, figure how you'd do it with a named array, then replace the name with a block that returns the reference.

If it's `$a[0]` for an named array, it's `${REF}[0]` for a reference to an array.

If it's `@a` for an named array, it's `@{REF}` for a reference to an array.

Easy!

```
my $i    =    ${ $linkarray }[0];
my @arr2 = @{ ${ $linkarray }[1] };
my @arr3 = @{ ${ $linkarray }[2] };
```

However, the following is easier to read:

```
my $i    =    $linkarray->[0];
my @arr2 = @{ $linkarray->[1] };
my @arr3 = @{ $linkarray->[2] };
```

Furthermore, you really shouldn't be making copies of those arrays like that. It's rather wasteful. Just work with the references.

```
my $i    = $linkarray->[0];
my $arr2 = $linkarray->[1];
my $arr3 = $linkarray->[2];
```

Finally, that simplifies to the following:

```
my ($i, $arr2, $arr3) = @$linkarray;
```

---

References:

- [Mini-Tutorial: Dereferencing Syntax](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=977408)
- [References quick reference](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=69927)
- [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)
- [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)
- [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)
- [perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html)